What triggers the change detection in an angular application when calling markForChange() method outside of Zonejs?
I am using the following code inside my component's constructor. The component is using the OnPush change detection strategy. As we can see, setTimeout executes outside the Angular zone, meaning zonejs will not be aware when the setTimeout operation has completed.
In this case, who informs Angular that something has changed and that it should trigger a change detection cycle?
I understand that markForCheck is responsible for marking the component and its ancestors as dirty, but my confusion is: how does Angular know when to start change detection since setTimeout is running outside the Angular zone?
 this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.count = 5;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();
  }, 3000);
})


If you want to know how you can look at the interior source code of markForCheck and the angular package.

Change detection OnPush does fire for only two scenarios:
Using OnPush - Angular.dev
Using OnPush

OnPush change detection instructs Angular to run change detection for a component subtree only when:

The root component of the subtree receives new inputs as the result of a template binding. Angular compares the current and past value of the input with ==.
Angular handles an event (for example using event binding, output binding, or @HostListener ) in the subtree's root component or any of its children whether they are using OnPush change detection or not.


Since your scenario does not match both these cases, the change detection is never run, unless you trigger it manually using ChangeDetectorRef.
Stackblitz for checking
